# Is the array sorted in decreasing, increasing or no order?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write code that tells me if an array is sorted. If the array is:

> - Sorted in increasing order ie. (1,2,3,4,5) , print 1.
> - Sorted in decreasing order ie (5,4,3,2,1) , print -1.
> - No order(1,2,1,4,1), print 0.

```
public static int isSorted(int[] a) {
int result=0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {

if (a[i] > a[i + 1]){
result=-1;

}else if (a[i] < a[i + 1] )  {
result=1;

}else{
result=0;       
}
}   
return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] a = { 9, 10, 9, 10, 12 };

System.out.println(isSorted(a));
}

}
```

My results now are not what i expect, for example the order now [9,10,9,10,12] should print a 0 but I'm getting a 1.

Can someone please help me? I think i need to change my conditions in the if/else-block.

Comment: You are overwriting `result` on every iteration of the loop, so you effectively only get the answer for the last two elements.

Comment: This is where formatting your code will make it easier to read and a debugger will show you where your bug is. You are only considering the last comparison. BTW `integer.compare(a, b)` will return -1, 1, or 0 comparing those values.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are overwriting the result variable in the loop, `result` will only represent the last check. In this case 10 <=> 12.

Try this one, with checks in the end.

```
public static int isSorted(int[] a) {
    boolean ascending = false;
    boolean descending = false;
    for (int currentIndex = 0, nextIndex = 1; nextIndex < a.length; currentIndex++, nextIndex++) {
        if (a[currentIndex] > a[nextIndex]) {
            descending = true;
        } else if (a[currentIndex] < a[nextIndex]) {
            ascending = true;
        } 
    }
    if ((descending && ascending) || (!descending && !ascending)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (descending) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i made a mistake the else clause in the loop should be `return 0;` instead of `return 1`

Comment: { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 } is still in ascending order right? I think you can remove the else clause altogether in the loop.

Comment: @StephanHogenboom Thank you, is there any way that i can change my if/else-conditions? 1,2,2,3,4 is no order if i understand my teacher.

Comment: if  two numbers after each others are equal mean no order, then only insert the `else return 0;` to the end of the loop.

Comment: @ElloMan93 did this help you? Would be nice to let Sunchezz know, since he put a lot of effort into helping you

Comment: @Sunchezz Thanks, i will look into your code. Sure it will help me a lot.